# Inheritance and the increment operator in Java

Tags: java

```
package com.company;
public class A {
    public int a(int b, int c) {
        return --b;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A a = new B();
        System.out.println(a.a(1000,1000));

    }
}

class B extends A {
    public int a(int b, int c) {
        if (b <= 0 && c == 0) {
            return ++b * ++c * ++b * c++;
        }
        return b > 0 ? a(super.a(b,c),c) : a(b, super.a(c,b));
    }
}
```

I compile the program:

> 2

I thought the output would be -999, 1000

The first thing I do is find the main method

> A a = new B();

So a variable A is created of type B

> System.out.println(a.a(1000,1000));

The a.a(1000,1000) calls the method public int a in class B (in class B not A, because the variable a is of type B)

Since b * c (1000,1000) do not meet the condition in the if statement, the if clause in the return statement is executed.

Since b > 0 then

> a(super.a(b,c),c) is called

The use of the super keywords means it is called the parent constructor in class A and returning --b, i.e. 1000 - 1 = 999 and C in the original method a in class B, which is equal to 1000

So it becomes

a(999,1000)

This will keep on going until B < 0, at which point it will call a(b, super.a(c,b) until c == 0, and finally return 2

However, is there a better way of analysing these (assuming you don't have access to a compiler)?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a more efficient way to read code?

Comment: You analized it correctly, I don't get your question. You have to compile it in your mind if you don't have access to a compiler, there are no alternatives :)

Comment: I recommend you avoid expressions like `++b * ++c * ++b * c++`. Yes, it is correct, but for supporting it is not clear at first eye. Have to analyze it. Don't you mind, that: `b++; c++; d++; int tmp = b * c * d * c; c++; return tmp;` is much more clear than one-line expression. Moreover, you cannot predict which of the `*` operators will be calculated first, because it is not in specification.

Answer (score 4):

The understanding is more in the side-effects of ++ and inheritance.

Simplified:

```
public int a(int b, int c) {
    if (b <= 0 && c == 0) {
        //return ++b * ++c * ++b * c++;
        //return ++b * 1 * ++b * 1;
        return (b+1) * (b+2);
        return 2; // When before recursion the original b >= 0
    }
    return b > 0 ? a(b-1, c) : a(c-1, b);
}
```

And that looks everything else than difficult.